# Impact migrating between multiple role models to one model IntegerField

Tags: python, django, django-models

In former times I was using three models named User (from AbstractBaseUser), Teacher and Student.

A Student could create a Request and a Teacher could ask to be responsible for that Request. If Student accepted, then the Teacher would become the responsible for that Request.

This is how the Request table looked like:

```
class Request(models.Model):
    request_id = models.CharField(db_column='requestId', primary_key=True, max_length=36)
    date_created = models.DateField(db_column='dateCreated')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    request_description = models.CharField(db_column='requestDescription', max_length=280, blank=True, null=True)
    expiration_date = models.DateField(db_column='expirationDate', blank=True, null=True)
    done = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='studentId')
    teacher_id = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='teacherId', blank=True, null=True)
```

As you can see, there's student_id and teacher_id with ForeignKey to, respectively, Student and Teacher models.

Now, I'm using only one model to represent User, Teacher and Student, called MyUser. In this model, got a field

```
user_type = models.IntegerField(db_column='userType')
```

where 0 is the MyUser with more permissions and 255 is an unspecified MyUser.

What happens now to the FKs in Request? Also, how to handle the Teacher and Student through this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to migrate your `Request` model in multiple steps as follows:

1. Add new nullable user fields for student and teacher WITHOUT deleting the old fields:

```
class Request(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='studentId')
    teacher_id = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='teacherId', blank=True, null=True)

    # new fields
    student = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, null=True, related_name='requests', limit_choices_to={'user_type': MyUser.USER_TYPE_STUDENT}, ...)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, null=True, related_name='student_requests', limit_choices_to={'user_type': MyUser.USER_TYPE_TEACHER}, ...)
```

2. Create a data migration file that populates these new fields based on the old fields:
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations
3. Update your code so all references to the old fields use the new fields, making sure you have validation on the application level allowing only the right types of `MyUser` assigned to each field
4. Make `Request.student` field non nullable.
5. Once you are sure the data has been migrated properly, you can delete the old fields. (this step is pretty optional, and can usually be delayed indefinitely until you are 100% sure all of the data has been migrated properly)

Comment: What will be, `MyUser.USER_TYPE_STUDENT` and `MyUser.USER_TYPE_TEACHER`?

Comment: You can replace those with whatever values you have for `user_type` that determines if the user is a student or a teacher